# Compiling OpenCV with Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.1

I have previously given up on installing OpenCV on my Windows 7 PC but now it has come back to haunt me, this time I'm trying to build its libraries using Visual Studio Community 2015.

I have tried finding a decent procedure on how to install it but they all sound simple until you encounter tons of errors when building ALL_BUILD in VS.

Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded the OpenCV 3.1 installer
2. Ran the installer and installed OpenCV in C:\
3. Added the OPENCV_DIR environment variable pointing to C:\opencv\build
4. Opened cmake-gui and set the source and build folders to C:\opencv\sources and C:\opencv\build, respectively
5. Clicked Configure, unchecked WITH_VTK option, clicked Configure again, then clicked Generate
6. Opened the generated solution file in C:\opencv\build
7. Right-clicked on the ALL_BUILD project and clicked Build

Only 11 projects were successfully built and 79 failed. The procedure they have on the OpenCV website is so outdated that it made me give up a long time ago. And there are several other resources that give equally confusing instructions.

Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further investigation, I saw this error frequently generated through build:

> ```
>   nvcc fatal   : nvcc cannot find a supported version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Only the versions 2010, 2012, and 2013 are supported
> ```

This is caused by CUDA not supporting Visual Studio 2015 yet. So, I unchecked WITH_CUDA in cmake-gui, clicked Generate, opened the generated OpenCV solution file and built ALL_BUILD. No errors were generated after that.